# Running python script via cgi and getting permission denied

Tags: apache, python-3.x, permissions

I am trying to run a python script which produces graphs and saves them to a folder.

I am running apache 2.4 on Ubuntu and my script works fine on the command line. The cgi module is enabled.

I have run permissions given to "all" for the script and I added the following code to my apache2.config file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/Python">
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py

<Directory /var/www/html/Python>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

According to the stuff I read online this should work, but the error log says that the permission was denied. What am I missing?

Comment: Was execution permission denied, or was permission to save the file denied?

Comment: the error logs say "can't open file", so I am guessing it is execution permission.